# How MYSQL do the redo operation?

Tags: mysql

We know in SQL server , the transaction log file contains both redo and undo log, however in the MYSQL transaction log ,it only contains the undo log , so how the MYSQL do the redo operation if it just writing just partial of the transaction data  for a successfully transaction ,then the server down?  As it is necessary to do the redo operation when reboot the server.

**Eidt, Sorry, I typo, I mean why MYSQL doesn't have the redo log instead of the undo log.**

Comment: Transaction either completes successfully or it fails if one query in transaction fails. That means a transaction **can't be partial**. If it's partial, it's not a transaction. Having established this, that means there's no problem with transactions. You have a problem with something else, so I suggest you write in details what it is.

Comment: @ Mjh, I mean partial writing the transaction data instead of the transaction suppose the transaction is very big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not done on MySQL level, this is taken care of the various table types that support transactions (e.g. innodb).

Innodb being the most widely used transactional table type in MySQL, my answer focuses on this table type only. For other transactional table types, see their own documentation on more info on the redo logs.

MySQL documentation on [innodb redo logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-redo-log.html) describe how innodb stores redo logs:

> By default, the redo log is physically represented on disk as a set of
>   files, named ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1. MySQL writes to the redo log
>   files in a circular fashion. Data in the redo log is encoded in terms
>   of records affected; this data is collectively referred to as redo.
>   The passage of data through the redo log is represented by an
>   ever-increasing LSN value.